# Allocate a vector of bytes on stack in assembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, stack, stack-memory

I try to put on stack the values contained by array_output but every time I print the values from the stack it prints just 0s.

If I try to print the array simple not using the stack it works.
What I do wrong?

```
stack_alloc:
    sub esp, 1
    mov al, byte [array_output + ecx]
    mov byte [esp], al
    add ecx, 1
    cmp ebx, ARRAY_OUTPUT_LEN
    cmp ebx, ecx
    jg stack_alloc
```

Comment: How do you print them? Post [mcve]. Note you are reversing the array. Also you should keep the stack aligned at least to 4 bytes and normally you allocate the memory in one step.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cmp ebx, ARRAY_OUTPUT_LEN
> cmp ebx, ecx
> jg stack_alloc
> ```

You have a typo in your code. The `cmp ebx, ARRAY_OUTPUT_LEN` instruction should not be comparing but rather **loading** the EBX register.
You could correct the problem replacing the `cmp` with a `mov` but I would propose to simplify your code and just compare the index in ECX to *ARRAY_OUTPUT_LEN*. This will require choosing the opposite conditional branch and saves from using the additional register EBX:

```
    xor ecx, ecx
stack_alloc:
    sub esp, 1
    mov al, [array_output + ecx]
    mov [esp], al
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, ARRAY_OUTPUT_LEN
    jb  stack_alloc
```